# Is it possible to change facebook omniauth app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth-facebook

We have been using the Facebook Omni auth feature to login users for a long time. Now the owner of the Facebook Omni auth app is not in contact with us, so we decided to create a new app and change the API keys on our website. Now existing users can't log in on our web page. Is it actually possible to change the Facebook Omni auth app and still do not get our web page broken? We are using Rails framework and [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) gem.

Comment: User ids are app-scoped since API v2.0, meaning each app will get to see a different user id for the same account. The only way to map them is adding both apps to the same business (and that you’ll manage to accomplish that is rather doubtful, if you are not in control of the original app.)

Comment: But I changed the API key on my development environment and even after migrating to the new app (API key) we were able to log in existing users. So what might have caused such behavior do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you mean, _“existing users can't log in”_? Do they get errors? Are new accounts created? ...?

Comment: Yes, they get an error. For example "user can't log in", and even we can't create new users. The error user get when they try to sign up is "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings." but we do have added all the URL in the app settings.